# Restrict access from www1 to www2 during an application hack

Tags: apache2

Lets say it was a symphony template and the upload feature was exploited and the hacker was able to gain access to this website, www1.  And now this hacker browses to www-2.. www-n.

I have apache web server.

How do I restrict application level hack/hacker from browsing to other www directories?